# Trigger execution >30s; doesn't make sense

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am updating a single cell in a Google Sheet when a change is made in the sheet, triggered by onEdit. Simple. I have used both a simple and installable trigger to do this, both seem to run longer than 30s. The installable trigger will at least complete though.

Why does this take so long to execute? Is there a faster way?

```
function updateTime(e) {
    var ss = e.source;
    ss.getRange("B"+e.range.getRow()).setValue(new Date());
}
```

Comment: It's very likely that you spreadsheet has a long recalculation time. Please add more details of your spreadsheet i.e. how many sheets, how many cells have each of them, how long it takes to load the spreadsheet (you can measure this by using Chrome DevTools > Performance Ctrl + Shift + E)

Comment: You were right! It takes a while to load, but that wasn't the main problem. I checked the spreadsheet settings and it had **iterative calculation** on. Duh. Thanks for pointing me at *recalculation*.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,2).setValue(new Date());
}
```

You shouldn't need an installable trigger

Comment: This is tighter, thanks. A simple trigger can timeout at 30s, and I find the onEdit execution times erratic. An installable trigger won't timeout, so it's more reliable.

Comment: if this is timing out then you must have more than one function tied to onEdit triggers or something you're not telling us about your situation.  Because this should not take that long.

Comment: I agree. It shouldn't. There are no other triggers or functions -- the reason was that iterative calculation was on.